# Notes app not showing collaborative edit option

Tags: notes.app, ios, iphone

I don't remember exactly the sequence of events, but I tried to update stock apps like Notes, Numbers, and Garage Band first before updating to iOS 10.

Now I am using iOS 10 smoothly but just noticed that Notes does have share notes (collaborative editing) feature added with this release. I went back to the App Store to find only an "Open" option for notes, and not update or download.

I noticed though I have Numbers and Garage Band on my phone, but it showed in the App Store that they need to be downloaded again.

I am new to iOS.

Comment: Notes is included with iOS and cannot be updated by itself. The only reason it appears in the App Store is with iOS 10, you can "delete" stock apps, and they put the reinstall option in the App Store - in reality, though, "deleting" a stock app just hides its icon from your home screen, and reinstalling it doesn't actually download anything. Numbers and Garage Band are not included with iOS and have to be downloaded/updated separately, but the App Store would not let you download a version that wasn't compatible with your version of iOS.

Comment: As far as Numbers and Garage Band showing as needing to be downloaded, if they appear like that, they are not actually installed on your device. What happens if you tap on the cloud icon to download them?

Comment: Thanks for quick comments @tubedogg and adding to my knowledge of iOS. I found out the issue, I had all my notes on my phone while trying to back them up on iCloud before trying to delete and re-install notes found out the missing option of collaboration edit is shown only in notes under notes on iCloud.

Comment: How to mark issue as resolved? Or not a issue?

Comment: You can post an answer on your own question - just put what you found out in the Your Answer box below. That way, if somebody else has this issue, they can easily see how it was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was not with the Notes app but the way I was using it. Collaborative edit is only possible in notes on iCloud and not "On My iPhone" ones. I had all my notes on the latter, so was not seeing the latest and greatest features.